# How to add a parent element when read in text file using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to use XSLT 2.0 to read in a text file and output an XML. The input text file is like:

```
Start:000,A:123,B:234,C:33,End:99,Start:03,A:123d,B:234s,End:992,Start:a00,B:234,C:33,End:99
```

And the desired XML output is like:

```
<File>
<Rec>
    <Start>000</Start>
    <A>123</A>
    <B>234</B>
    <C>33</C>
    <End>99</End>
</Rec>
<Rec>
    <Start>03</Start>
    <A>123d</A>
    <B>234s</B>
    <End>992</End>
</Rec>
<Rec>
    <Start>a00</Start>
    <B>234</B>
    <C>33</C>
    <End>99</End>
</Rec>
```

I have difficulty grouping elements from "Start" to "End" and adding a parent element "Rec" to it. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: XSLT is about transforming XML documents; it's realy not the right tool for dealing with plain, unstructured text files.  You'd probably better off with a small script (Python, Perl, even bash...  anything you feel comfortable with).

Comment: @xbug - That's a fair statement, but when it's a simple transform like the one in this question, XSLT is fine. Especially when the resulting XML is going to be transformed further. Sometimes it's handy to transform unparsed text into XML and save it in a variable to use elsewhere in a transform. Otherwise you're having to mix technologies (which isn't always a bad thing; especially when you're using another language to run the XSLT).

Comment: @xbug - XSLT 2.0 handles this kind of task as well as any other language.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `unparsed-text()` and `tokenize()` to create the output you're looking for. If the text file might have more than one line, you could also use `xsl:analyze-string`.

Example...

**Text Input** (so.txt)

```
Start:000,A:123,B:234,C:33,End:99,Start:03,A:123d,B:234s,End:992,Start:a00,B:234,C:33,End:99
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="input-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'so.txt'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text($input-uri, $input-encoding)"/>
        <File>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'Start')[string()]">
                        <Rec>
                            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')[string()]">
                                <xsl:variable name="vals" select="tokenize(.,':')"/>
                                <xsl:element name="{if (position()=1) then 'Start' else $vals[1]}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$vals[2]"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>                            
                        </Rec>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<File>
   <Rec>
      <Start>000</Start>
      <A>123</A>
      <B>234</B>
      <C>33</C>
      <End>99</End>
   </Rec>
   <Rec>
      <Start>03</Start>
      <A>123d</A>
      <B>234s</B>
      <End>992</End>
   </Rec>
   <Rec>
      <Start>a00</Start>
      <B>234</B>
      <C>33</C>
      <End>99</End>
   </Rec>
</File>
```

Comment: Master, hats of to your logics. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by tokenizing, then grouping.

```
<xsl:variable name="raw" as="element()*">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(unparsed-text('input.txt')), ',')">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(., ':')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ':')"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<File>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$raw" group-starting-with="Start">
    <Rec>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </Rec>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</File>
```